# How to replace a string containing "\u2015"?

Tags: linux, sed, sh

Does anyone know how to replace a string containing `\u2015` in a SED command like the example below?

```
sed -ie "s/some text \u2015 some more text/new text/" inputFileName
```

Comment: Depends on what `\u2015` represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape the slashes present. Below example works fine in `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

```
$ echo "some text \u2015 some more text" | sed -e "s/some text \\\u2015 some more text/abc/"
$ abc
```

Also you don't have to use the `-i` flag which according to the the `man` page is only for editing `files` in-place.

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

    edit  files  in place (makes backup if extension supplied).  The default operation mode is to break symbolic and hard links.  This can be changed with --follow-symlinks and
          --copy.
```

Comment: Never use double quotes around a script, always use single. In this case if you do that you'll find you don't need so many escapes.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but maybe you should take a look at `native2ascii` tool to convert such unicode escapes.

Normally it replaces all characters that cannot be displayed in ISO-8859-1 with their unicodes (escaped with \u), but it also supports reverse conversions. Assuming you have some file in UTF-8 named "input" containing `\u00abSome \u2015 string\u00bb`, then executing

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 -reverse input output
```

will result in "output" file with `«Some ― string»`.